# How to set CMake variable of type list from command line

Tags: cmake

I am trying to do something like this

```
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DCMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES=ReleaseDebug
```

But the `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES` is not set as a `list` variable. I also tried

```
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DCMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES="Release Debug"
```

which didn't work either.

How to do it the right way?

Comment: Maybe `-DCMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES="Release;Debug"`?

Comment: @arrowd that worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lists are special type of strings in CMake. When you write `set(var a b c)` it is equivalent to `set(var "a;b;c")`. The same applies to your case. CMake interprets `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES` variable as a list, so you need to write `-DCMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES="Release;Debug"` to properly set it from the command line.