# Expanding Variables in Cmake

Tags: cmake

I'm a new cmake user, trying to define a resource file to display version information in my executable. I'm having issues getting variables to expand correctly. I use the following code in my CMakeLists.txt

```
set(
FILE_VERSION_MAJOR " 1"
FILE_VERSION_MINOR " 2"
FILE_VERSION_PATCH " 3")

set(FILE_VERSION ${FILE_VERSION_MAJOR}, ${FILE_VERSION_MINOR}, ${FILE_VERSION_PATCH}, 0)

configure_file(
  src/resource.rc.in
  resource.rc
  )
```

Which connects to this line in my resource.rc.in

```
#define VER_FILE_VERSION @FILE_VERSION@
```

Which results in the following in my resource.rc file

```
#define VER_FILE_VERSION 
@FILE_VERSION_MAJOR@,;@FILE_VERSION_MINOR@,;@FILE_VERSION_PATCH@,;0
```

How do I get the final VER_FILE_VERSION to display as 1, 2, 3, 0 in my resource.rc file?

*Note, my question is not about using the command line

Comment: Add quotes around `set` argument. See [How to set CMake variable of type list from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47842962/how-to-set-cmake-variable-of-type-list-from-command-line)

Comment: Is `@FILE_VERSION_MAJOR@` what you **literaly** have in the resulted file? It would be very strange, as CMake doesn't emit character `@` by itself. Or is `@FILE_VERSION_MAJOR@` just a *placeholder*, and the **actual** output is "1"? Note, that *single* `set` command cannot set *several* variables. In the current code you set `FILE_VERSION_MAJOR` variable to the list of (literaly! but without double quotes): `" 1"`, `"FILE_VERSION_MINOR"`, `" 2"`, `"FILE_VERSION_PATCH"`, `" 3"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. you missed the quotes while setting your `FILE_VERSION`. Therefore that you used ',' without the quote, you declared a list
2. your first set tries to set multiple variables. this does not work.

With this CMakeLists.txt everything works as expected:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project(Test)

set(FILE_VERSION_MAJOR "1")
set(FILE_VERSION_MINOR "2")
set(FILE_VERSION_PATCH "3")

set(FILE_VERSION "${FILE_VERSION_MAJOR}, ${FILE_VERSION_MINOR}, ${FILE_VERSION_PATCH}")

message(${FILE_VERSION})
```