# how to run compound script statements from cmake?

Tags: cmake

I have a complex/compound command that I want to execute as patch command during execution of my ExternProject_Add using this macro

```
macro(SET_PATCH_CMD arg)
  message(STATUS "Patch command : ${arg};${ARGN}")
  set(${PROJECT_NAME}_patch_cmd ${arg};${ARGN})
endmacro(SET_PATCH_CMD)
```

I dont remeber or am not sure why I added a ; between ${arg} and ${ARGN}, but patch commands like

```
mkdir -p <SOURCE_DIR>/install
```

are working as expected in my cmake project.

When I set a simple command like

```
SET(PATCH_CMD <SOURCE_DIR>/scripts/my_schript.sh)
```

patch command executes as expected, but the moment I start adding arguments to script with spaces in between

```
SET(PATCH_CMD <SOURCE_DIR>/scripts/my_schript.sh arg1 arg2 arg3)
SET_PATCH_CMD(${PATCH_CMD})
```

I get Command failed: No such file or directory

clearly spaces in my command are messing up the way cmake runs the shell script/command. Any help on making it work is appreciated.

Comment: Show the code where you use this macro. Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47853645/637669

Comment: @arrowd thanks for providing link on list type in cmake. I added the macro usage code, nothing special, simple call of macro with ${PATCH_CMD} argument